# How to deactivate all the old versions of APK's in NEW Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

We are having an Android App, which is currently supporting API 16 and above. The very old version ( before approx six releases ) was supporting API 14.

When releasing new version, we are able to deactivate the currently active version in the NEW Google play console.

But we have following issues, in NEW Google play console.

1) We can not view very old APK versions ( we are able to see the list of past three versions only )

2) We are unable to deactivate any of other older versions.

As older versions are not deactivated, the users of older Android devices ( with older versions below 16 ) can download the older versions of APK. This versions does not work properly in current conditions, so it is very important for us to deactivate older versions.

I have tried to search for the issue, but could get answers for older Google Play console.

Thanks in advance for any help ...

Regards
Sanjay.

Comment: Any solutions? Common it's 2018 already and no solution from Google yet :(

Comment: @Husyn - We are handling currently by manual support calls of users.

Answer (score 1):

1. I try in my console, but i still see all older release: App release -> Manage product -> release history. Can you post your image here.
2. And as you know, each time when new version was released, old version will be deactivated automatically. Are you sure that older android version can get older app version because older version is not deactivated yet ? or because you can't view older app version so you think that it's not deactivated ?

Comment: The image link   http://dgflick.in/_img/Prasadik_IMAGE.png   of release history.  Yesterday an android user can download older version 2.0 of App, on his mobile device having older android version.

Comment: please expand 4.0 release. How can you know that he download older version ? If just because he have 2.0 version, maybe he not upload yet ?

Comment: When I expand 4.0, I do NOT get any entry of deactivated versions. When I expand 4.5, I can see the deactivated entry of version 4.0. But there is no any mention of older version 2.0. Which is still available for download. We are displaying version number in our first screen of app, so we are sure of old version app.